# How do I get the Github Actions section in the Visual Studio solution view?

Tags: github-actions, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 17.5 and I am not sure if this is a new feature of just this version, but in one of my solutions (and only one - that's the strange thing) I now can see the Github Actions directly in the solution view (which is great):
[image]

In general, how can I get this section/view?

Comment: Looks like VS recognizes GHA workflows and shows their YAML configs in the Solution Explorer. I guess for any project that has GHA workflows VS will show those like that.

Comment: For the ones who do not even have this "GitHub actions" showing up, in my case I updated to VS22 to 17.6 and it appeared automatically. I already had a .yml in my repo under .github/workflow before updating.

Answer (score 5):

See: https://blog.elmah.io/9-hidden-features-in-visual-studio-that-you-may-not-know/

In the second feature about 'GitHub Actions in Solution Explorer' it states:

> For now, the 'GitHub Actions' node only shows as long as there's an ASP.NET Core project in the solution. I'm hoping Microsoft will include this for all project types.

As a test I added an ASP.NET Core project to a class library containing some GitHub Actions. After reloading the project, these became visible.

I'm using VS 17.8.3

Edit: You need to open the solution from within the VS IDE to have the GitHub Actions node showing in the Solution Explorer. Opening the solution by double clicking the solution in the File Explorer does not show the node. This is a known bug in VS. See comments below.

Comment: In my case, I'm using `react + asp.net core web api` (defaul VS template) and I don't see this section in solution exporer

Comment: Also using the React template I see the GitHub Actions node showing up. My steps: create solution using React template in VS, push solution to a (new) GitHub repository, add some yml-files in .github\workflows folder, push those, reload project.

Comment: hmm, I did the same, which tempale exaclty you have used?

Comment: I've tested the JavaScript and also the TypeScript templates. I've made a temporary minimal public GitHub repo to test: https://github.com/mdekok/ReactApp1. After cloning and opening the solution I did not see the GitHub Actions as well. This was by opening the solution by double clicking the solution file. But after closing the solution and reopening in the Visual Studio IDE the GitHub Actions did show in the Solution Explorer. Seems to be a bug in Visual Studio. Maybe this is also the reason you don't see this section in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: I see this happening also in my own solutions, which are no React solutions, if I open them from the File Explorer. So opening the solution from within the Visual Studio IDE does seem the trick, for now.

Comment: wow, ` But after closing the solution and reopening in the Visual Studio IDE the GitHub Actions did show in the Solution Explorer.` - this is the case... Works no for me too. Thanks!

Comment: *Works now for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Version 17.5 added this (it seems like around the release of [.NET 7 this was added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.4#net-7-is-available-today)), but regardless, there is a setting currently in the preview features to enable this.  If you go to Tools → Options → Environment → Preview Features, you can find it:

[image: github actions settings in preview features]

Microsoft has some-what limited documentation about this.  I found two resources:

- [An overview of the GitHub Actions integration in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/overview-github-actions?view=vs-2022)
- [Deploy your application to Azure using GitHub Actions workflows created by Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/azure-deployment-using-github-actions?view=vs-2022)

In the first link, it states:

> If your codebase is hosted on GitHub.com and your deployment target is an Azure hosting service that Visual Studio supports, you will automatically be offered to configure GitHub Actions for your repo.

I am *guessing* that Visual Studio looks for a `.github/workflows` folder in your solution's root and pulls in any of the YAML files present.

Comment: This answer does not seem to address why GitHub Actions are shown for one solution, but not shown for another solution.  Both solutions have GitHub Action yml files in the same place relative to the solution.

Comment: sounds at least partially it's a bug in VS, see comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77787667/9133885