# Github actions are not shown in solution explorer in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, github-actions, solution-explorer

In my newly created VS project that is created from "React and ASP.NET Core" template, I have github actions definitions automatically created by github in `%ROOT%\.github\workflows\` folder, but I don't see these files in the Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio.

I saw somewhere that it doesn't work yet if the solution doesn't contain ASP.NET Core project, but in my case, I do have an ASP.NET Core Web API project. Can someone shed some light on this?

To clarify: I mean auto finding github action files and grouping them under folder like:

[image]

Comment: That's where exactly VS and VS Code differ. If you want the "Folder view" experience, learn how to open it, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/use-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022

Comment: @LexLi, no, it's completely about different thing

Comment: No. I don’t think what you asked was implemented as part of Visual Studio, and search engines didn’t show an extension with that feature either.

Comment: @LexLi, It does and I saw it before. Also mentioned in few articles for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75537987/how-do-i-get-the-github-actions-section-in-the-visual-studio-solution-view

Comment: Then there is almost nothing you or others here can do but to wait till this becomes a stable feature of Visual Studio. To provide your feedback to Microsoft, follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 1):

How did you open the solution? Try starting Visual Studio and then use File->Open... to open the solution.

There is a known problem with "GitHub Actions" missing with opening via right-click or other means.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/GitHub-Actions-disappeared-from-Solution/10448199?ftype=problem&q=GitHub+Actions

Comment: yes, it's mentioned in the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77787667/9133885. I also reported a new report to VS support